# Build with CMake on Visual Studio Online hosted agent

Tags: cmake, azure-devops

How to get Visual Studio Online build step "CMake" working on their hosted agents pool?
[Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool) says that CMake should be available on the build server, but there is no "cmake" capability in "Control Panel/Agent Pool/Hosted Agent".

More details:

1. I'm trying to queue hosted build that includes "CMake" step, but message appears: "**There are issues with the request or definition that may prevent the build from running:No agent could be found with the following capabilities: cmake, msbuild, visualstudioQueue the build anyway?**"
2. Looking in "Control Panel/Agent Pool/Hosted Agent" I can't see "cmake" capability in the list. [image: capabilities list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was confirmed as a bug by Microsoft, it should be fixed in next build server image update. Till that moment problem may be solved this way:

1. Create a .bat with the below command in it and check it in to source control
       SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\;%PATH%
2. Add a BATCH SCRIPT task that runs the .BAT from step 1 sometime before the CMAKE task.
3. Check the Modify Environment option of the BATCH SCRIPT task (this is so the PATH change persists into the CMAKE task.
4. Add the CMake capability on the hosted pool with the area path C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe

Answer (score 4):

Right, the fact that you don't see cmake in the list of Hosted build agent capabilities means that hosted agent is not designed to run cmake builds.

When you add a CMake build step to your build definition, the engine automatically adds cmake as one of the demands, because [the task definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CMake/task.json) requires that:

```json
"name": "CMake",
"friendlyName": "CMake",
...
"demands" : [
    "cmake"
],
```

The task itself assumes the cmake.exe is in PATH on the build agent. Look at [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CMake/CMake.ps1):

```bsh
try
{
    $cmake = Get-Command cmake.exe
    Write-Verbose ('Using {0}' -f $cmake.Path)
}
catch
{
    throw (Get-LocalizedString -Key 'Unable to find {0}' -ArgumentList 'cmake.exe')
}
```

So, although the hosted agent works like this by design and you can't control this, this is what you should do to make another build agent comply with cmake:

- Install cmake on the build agent and make sure cmake.exe is in the path
- Add CMake as a capability to the build agent. This can be done explicitly, by adding a custom capability in the web UI, or implicitly, by authoring an environment variable called "cmake" on the build agent, and TFS will find it automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the presence of CMake in the [list](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool) of software on hosted build server is Microsoft's mistake?

Comment: @OlegMax, hmm, that's funny. I was not aware about the fact there's an explicit list of supported software. In this case it does look like a bug. Or a half-baked feature ;-) The version of build agents is constantly updating, perhaps the future versions will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To build with CMake on VSO hosted agent pool, you need to add the CMake build step to the build definition. See:

[image]

Comment: Of course, I did that. Please check the updated question.